# When trying to use the google authentication method in flutter web gives error

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin

Good, I'm making an application with registration and login in flutter web using the method that provides firebaseauth and applying it with google sign-in, the thing is that when I hit the button and put my account in the console I get this error:

```
[GSI_LOGGER-TOKEN_CLIENT]: Trying to set gapi client token.
[GSI_LOGGER-TOKEN_CLIENT]: The OAuth token was not passed to gapi.client, 
since the gapi.client library is not loaded in your page.
```

The `auth_service.dart` which is where I have the code to start session with google is the following:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

class AuthService {
  // google sign in
  signInWithGoogle() async {
    // begin interactive sign in process
    final GoogleSignInAccount? gUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

    //obtain auth details from request
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication gAuth = await gUser!.authentication;

    //create a new credential for user
    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: gAuth.accessToken, idToken: gAuth.idToken);

    //finally, lets sign in
    return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
  }
}
```

I have put in the `index.html` the id that firebase generates for you to be able to log in with the account.

I have tried it on mobile and it works correctly, but when it comes to the web, I register or log in but I don't get past the login screen.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Google Sign In docs for Flutter Web

> The plugin `signIn` method uses the OAuth "Implicit Flow" to Authorize the requested scopes.
> This method only provides an accessToken, and not an idToken, so if your app needs an idToken, this method should be avoided on the web.
> [Source](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in_web)

The solution to this is to migrate your custom "Sign In" buttons in the web to the Button Widget provided by the package: `Widget renderButton()`.

https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in/example

This is a full example app properly using the `renderButton()` widget but here is a short summary:

Setup a `onCurrentUserChanged`:

```
final gsi = GoogleSignIn(
  clientId: <YOUR CLIENT ID>,
  scopes: ["email"],
);

gsi.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((GoogleSignInAccount? account) async {
  if (account != null) {
    final authentication = await account.authentication;
    final idToken = authentication.idToken;
    final accessToken = authentication.accessToken;

    //Perform the firebase sign in
    //TODO: Do something with the result.
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
    
  } else {
    // Not authenticated yet.
  }
});
```

Render the Google provided Sign in button in your UI.
The Sign in library provides a small level of customization for the sign in button, in my example below it will render as a circular 'G' icon button:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in_platform_interface/google_sign_in_platform_interface.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in_web/google_sign_in_web.dart' as web;


/// Renders a web-only SIGN IN button.
Widget googleSignInButton({HandleSignInFn? onPressed}) {
  final config = web.GSIButtonConfiguration(
    type: web.GSIButtonType.icon,
    shape: web.GSIButtonShape.pill,
    size: web.GSIButtonSize.large,
  );
  return (GoogleSignInPlatform.instance as web.GoogleSignInPlugin)
      .renderButton(configuration: config);
}

class SomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Google Sign In Example'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          const Text("Sign in with"),
          googleSignInButton(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It's important to note that this code will not work outside of Flutter Web, so you should do something like a stub class with conditional imports to properly load the code for only the web environment.
[Example of that here.](https://medium.com/flutter-community/conditional-imports-across-flutter-and-web-4b88885a886e)

Finally, when the users clicks the rendered sign in button it will start the OAuth flow, when the completes you will get a callback in your `onCurrentUserChanged` stream.